# Error during ctex package installation - permission denied

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I encountered the following error while attempting to download and install the package ctex via the MikTex Console.

> Permission denied: path="C:\Program Files\MikTeX
> 2.9\tex/generic/ctex/zhmap", modeString="wb"

This is the info I obtained from the consoles error log via the 'Copy Info' Button.

> GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION ReportDate: 2021-03-20 19:37:33
>
> CurrentVersion: 21.3
>
> SetupDate: 2018-04-26 20:38:00
>
> SetupVersion: 2.9
>
> Configuration: Regular
>
> GitInfo: ab8ebca / 2021-03-19 10:22:46
>
> OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 19042
>
> SharedSetup: no
>
> LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
>
> PathOkay: yes
>
> SystemAdmin: yes
>
> RootPrivileges: yes
>
> AdminMode: no
>
> Root0: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Root1: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Root2: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
>
> Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> UserInstall: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
>
> UserConfig: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> UserData: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9
>
> CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
>
> Invokers: non-existing/explorer
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>
> Program: C:\Program Files\MikTeX
> 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
>
> Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:567
>
> Error: Permission denied: path="C:\Program Files\MikTeX
> 2.9\tex/generic/ctex/zhmap", modeString="wb"
>
> Details:
>
> path: C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ctex/zhmap
>
> modeString: wb

I have made sure that MikTex Console runs in Administrator mode, yet I keep getting the error above. Is there a way to resolve this issue without having to reinstall MikTex from scratch?

Comment: The latest version of ctex has an error.  What should be a folder zhmap has been mis-written as a file.  I have asked about this is question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588319/can-the-ctex-update-error-be-fixed-by-users?noredirect=1#comment1477928_588319 but got no answer.  I think we just have to wait for them to repair the ctex package.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty sitting there and waiting doesn't resolve problems. You have to do something. I now added an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/236, but I wished people using this packages would do this themselves.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Confluentius reported it 2 days ago github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/756  so I did not know another report would be needed. For now, apparently there is no patch users can apply, and we must wait for a correcting update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ctex package has been repaired.  I just re-installed it and it works for me.

This error message was due to an error in the March 21 version of ctex. You actually should not have permission to modify zhmap the way that version wanted to.  Rather zhmap has to be a folder rather than a file in ctex.   There was apparently nothing you (or I who share the problem) could do overcome that.  The issue has been fixed now.