# Can the ctex update error be fixed by users?

Tags: cjk, miktex-update

I've been using ctex for a couple of years, but the latest MiKTeX update breaks it.

This issue has  been reported at the miktex issue tracker, and it was closed there when the OP of that issue posted

```
In tex/generic/ctex zhmap is a file but should be a folder.
```

To be clear, this is an error in the update.  The update turns zhmap into a file, and then does not work.

Do I have to wait for someone to re-update ctex making zhmap back into a folder?  Or can I fix this on my machine? I do not see any obvious way to turn zhmap into a folder.

Comment: Why don't you open an issue at the miktex issue tracker?